# How can I get an xml button to properly intialize to enabled?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.forms

I have the following content within my activity_main.xml

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/id_SubStationMenu"
        layout="@layout/locationmenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/id_Sheet1"
        layout="@layout/id_Sheet1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/id_Sheet2"
        layout="@layout/id_Sheet2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <include
        android:id="@id/id_Sheet3"
        layout="@layout/id_Sheet3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

The SubStationMenu has a button that is working properly (set to enabled when another button is pressed), whenever that button is pressed it takes the user into one of the Id_Sheets. Each ID sheet has the following included layout

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/id_Sheet1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <include
        layout="@layout/stationlog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/id_ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="640dp">
        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_GridLayoutInsideScrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:rowCount="2">
            <include
                layout="@layout/patients"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </GridLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</GridLayout>
```

The problem I'm having occurs within the stationlog

```
<include
        layout="@layout/stationlog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

this layout has a button that should be enabled when entering sheet1, sheet2, or sheet3.

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/id_ExitToMenu"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="@string/Exit"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:enabled="false"
            />
```

Whenever I enter a sheet, this button should be enabled like so

```
Button exitButton = activity.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.id_ExitToMenu);
                exitButton.Enabled = true;
```

this is done with 3 if else checks to see which sheet the user has entered via a string location.

```
if (location == "sheet1")
{
    EnableViews(activity, location);
}
else if (location == "sheet2")
{
    EnableViews(activity, location);
}
else if (location == "sheet3")
{
    EnableViews(activity, location);
}

//Method to enable views
private void EnableViews(Activity activity, string location)
{
    TextView title = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.id_StationTitle);
    title.Text = location;
    Button exitButton = activity.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.id_ExitCountSheetButton);
    exitButton.Enabled = true;

    LinearLayout dateTimeName = activity.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.id_DateTimeName);
    for (int i = 0; i < dateTimeName.ChildCount; i++)
    {
        View view = dateTimeName.GetChildAt(i);
        if (view is EditText editText)
        editText.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

For some reason the only sheet with the exitButton being properly initialized and interactive is sheet1.

Whenever debugging everything seems to work correctly in the code, but when the layout is displayed the button isn't enabled. Preventing the user from exiting the menu.

Things I've tried:

1. placing the `exitButton.Enabled = true` behind the if checks (I know the menus will be opened regardless)
2. Placing the Layout/StationLog in the mainlayout and removing it from the 3 sheets so they would wrap on top of each other
3. Debugging to ensure the button is being enabled properly (it is?) but when I get to the menu it is grayed out.

To reiterate, I've noticed that sheet1 always works. The button gets enabled properly and shows up properly on the layout for the user. But the button does not show up as enabled for sheet2 or sheet3 (even though when debugging it appears to). The code for sheet1, sheet2, and sheet3 are almost identical. Does anyone have any thoughts as to why the button would be enabled for one sheet, but not the other two?

Comment: instead of describing the code - "this is done with 3 if else checks" - please post the actual code

Comment: @jason I went ahead and added the code to the question.

Comment: @Luichigo15 was correct, I had to establish new id's for the 3 included layouts. I also had to add click events to each button even though I thought I wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all to compare Strings it is better to use equals() method, sometimes comparing with '==' makes things working weird.

Also, if I understood well all sheets are inside the same layout, so you are using the same id more than one time. The id must be unique in every component